# git перестал автоматически добавлять новые файлы

Tags: git

После каких-то манипуляций во всех репозиториях гита на компе перестали опознаваться новые файлы, раньше я мог в директории создать новый файлик, гит его сразу видел как новый.

Сейчас не видит, помогает только добавление через меню Add, пользуюсь тортугой.

Comment: Может быть конечно это делала Visual studio раньше, не знаю, но щас это не присходит тоже, но в студии через team explorer эти файлы показывает в статусе added тогда как сам гит через черепашку запихивает эти файлы в unversioned

Comment: А что если зайти в git bash и выполнить `git status`?

Comment: думаю, что эти файлы попали в список git ignore. Может туда кто то дописал `*.*`?

Comment: "сам гит через черепашку запихивает эти файлы в unversioned" -- это так-то ожидаемое поведение...

Comment: "сам гит через черепашку запихивает эти файлы в unversioned" -- это так-то ожидаемое поведение...

Может это конечно делала сама студия, но раньше так было

Comment: Нет гитигнор тут не причем вообще, даже в репозиториях без гитигнора такая ерунда, гит баш тоже показывает их в статусе Untracked

Answer (score 1):

Сам добавлять файлы в репозиторий git не умеет, делаешь это ты с помощью команды:

```
$ git add /path/to/file/file.txt
```

что бы добавить все файлы вводишь из корня проекта:

```
$ git add *
```

з.ы. без $ вводишь

Comment: Я же говорю, может это студия делала, щас настройки сбились